# pass random number to onchange function

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

On change I am trying to pass a random number in to the function. In Firefox it's working fine but in Chrome its not working and its not even throwing an error and code written inside is not getting executed

if i remove rand the code inside will work fine

```js
$(document.body).on('change', '.hiddenupload', function (e, rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1)) {
    array[rand]=$(this);
   //other code
}
```

how can i solve this??

Comment: Are you sure the console is not showing an error?

Comment: yes i rechecked again its not throwing error

Comment: wait its giving error at =

Comment: I answered you already 

Comment: i really need send a random number how can i achieve this

Comment: [Partial Application](http://ejohn.org/blog/partial-functions-in-javascript/)

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript you can't assign values to variables as function parameters. So you have to pass a variable, object, function, string or number, but you can't assign values.

```
function(a, function(b, c){  }) // works

function(a, {b: c}) // works

function(a = b, c) // does not work in javascript
```

**Edit:**

As workaround, you can assign that variable inside the function directly:

```
$(document.body).on('change', '.hiddenupload', function (e) {
    var rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1);
});
```

Comment: First notice that I have. I didn't know it. From MDN: *"This is a new technology, part of the ECMAScript 2015 (ES6) standard ."*. You can check [DOCS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters). Only Firefox support it.